# cannot reference variable name "id" more than once

Tags: php, laravel

I need to delete booking by ID in my sub event id

[image]

```php
 Route::delete('event/{id}/booking/{id}', 'bookingController@destroy');
```

My Controller

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        booking::destroy($booking->id);
        return redirect('event')->with('flash_message', 'ลบข้อมูลการสำรองที่นั่งเรียบร้อย');
    }
```

My from Method Delete

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('event/' . $event->id .'/booking/' . $booking->id) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display:inline">
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete event" onclick="return confirm(&quot;Confirm delete?&quot;)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>ยกเลิกการจอง</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: `event/{eventId}/booking/{bookingId}`

Comment: Note that `$booking` is undefined in your controller's method

Answer (score 0):

Your route has two variables (event_id) and (booking_id), yet your method only has one ($id)
Using your existing route (which is not tbh adhering to how eloquent works)

web.php

```
Route::delete('event/{event_id}/booking/{booking_id}', 'bookingController@destroy')->name('booking.destroy');
```

blade

```
action = "{{ route('booking.destroy', $event_id, $booking_id) }}"
```

controller

```
public function destroy ($booking_id, $event_id)
```

You might want to take a look at laravel relationships here:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Will make your life much easier, thus eloquent will pass an instance and your destroy method will look like this

```
public function destroy (Booking $booking)
{
 $event = $booking->event();
 // Do something with related event
 // or vice versa
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the IDs two separate IDs? Or do they share the same ID?

If they are two separate IDs, then you need to give them two explicitly different names, e.g. booking_id and event_id and then you would be able to access them in the Controller like you want.

```
 Route::delete('event/{event_id}/booking/{booking_id}', 'bookingController@destroy');
```

Then in your controller you can do

```
    public function destroy($event_id, $booking_id)
    {
        ...
    }
```

If I recall correctly, the parameters in the controller method do not need to be named the exact same as the ones in the route (although it'd make your life easier). The parameters are passed in order, so you could do

```
    //$A = event_id, $B = booking_id
    public function destroy($A, $B)
    {
        ...
    }
```